# Final field initialization in an Activity constructor

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any problem in this code?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private final String[] names;

    public MyActivity() {
        names = new String[]{
            getString(R.string.strion_one),
            getString(R.string.string_two),
            getString(R.string.string_three),
        };
    }    

    ...

}
```

Comment: initialize it in `onCreate` do not create a constructor of activity class

Comment: But what if I want to have a final fiend?

Comment: And do not use final when its members are all fetched using `getString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i right understand your problem, you try to create a class, which contains links on your resources. So i recommend you to create a class which will be contains links on your resources.

```
 public class MyResources{

    private final String[] myStrings;
    public MyResources(Context context)
    {
        myStrings = new String[]{};
        myStrings[0] = context.getResources().getString(R.string.string_one);
        myStrings[100] = context.getResources().getString(R.string.string_one_hun);
    }

    public String getStringAtNumber(int value)
    {
        return myStrings[0];
    }
}
```

And yes! One more thing. You can get resources only after `onCreate` execute.